# Best way to wrap Java classes into Python

Tags: java, python, wrapper, py4j

I have a Java library and I have to build a Python wrapper to it.

I am using [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/), and it's pretty easy to get any instance and any class, complete with method.

The problem is that the type of an object doesn't correspond to its class.

From python:

```
>>> gw = JavaGateway()
>>> a_circle = gw.jvm.com.geometry.Circle(15)
>>> a_circle.getDiameter()
30
>>> type(a_circle)
<class 'py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject'>
```

This is almost ok for basic usage, but what if I want to create custom constructors? Should I subclass the `JavaObject` class? Or it's better to create my classes from scratch and for every method and constructor invoke the corresponding Java method?

Any suggestion for a good way to achieve it? Should i try something different than py4j?
Thank you!

EDIT: for example, I have to wrap a Java class that has 3 methods, one of those methods takes an array as parameter, so I have to inject some code in order to convert.

```
class Service:
    def __init__(self, javaService):
    '''
    Create a new instance of Service, assigning Java methods as attributes.
    Accepts a working instance of Service from Java
    This constructor is not meant to be called by the user.
    '''

    self.subscribe = javaService.subscribe
    self.unsubscribe = javaService.unsubscribe

    def publish(values):
        '''
        Wraps the java implementation of this method, converting the list of value from a Python iterable to a Java list.
        '''
        global java_gateway
        parameterValues = ListConverter().convert(values, java_gateway._gateway_client)
        return javaService.publish(values)
    self.publish = publish
```

This works, but I am doing only when it is necessary. If the class just works directly, I am not writing anything to wrap it.

Comment: Hi, can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve, e.g., what the end code should look like? Specifically, what do you mean by "but what if I want to create custom constructors"?

Comment: @Barthelemy I have edited the question with an example. Actually there isn't much to say, the code works, I was just wondering if there is a template, a good practice for wrapping.

Comment: Have you tried [JPype](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/)? It is a very mature approach for wrapping Java classes into Python classes, as Pythonically as possible.